# What is .deploy extension in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I publish my software using Visual Studio it makes .deploy extension.
E.g. my_program.exe.deploy
what is it? what is it used for

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx

Comment: This is not related to MSDeploy, removing the tag.

Answer (score 22):

When you publish a ClickOnce application, it appends ".deploy" on all of the files on the deployment site. The reason for this is that many people deploy to a webserver, and it keeps them from having to set up MIME types for every single type of file included in the deployment. When the deployment is installed on the client machine, it removes the .deploy from the files.